# Запятая перед "лишь" + деепричастие

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия, деепричастный-оборот

Уважаемые знатоки, кто-нибудь может сказать, обоснована ли запятая перед словом "лишь" и если да, то каким правилом она объясняется?

> *Продолжать переход можно, лишь убедившись в безопасности дальнейшего движения и с учетом сигнала светофора*

Answer (score 3):

> *Продолжать переход можно, лишь убедившись в безопасности дальнейшего движения и с учетом сигнала светофора.*
>
> ...обоснована ли запятая перед словом "лишь", и если да, то каким
>   правилом она объясняется?

Указанная запятая **нужна.**

См. [***"Полный академический справочник":***](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121)

> **§ 68.** Обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами, выделяются запятыми, независимо от места расположения по отношению к
>   глаголу-сказуемому...
>
> **§ 69.** Ограничительные частицы ***только, лишь,*** стоящие перед деепричастными оборотами, включаются в их состав, **и запятая ставится
>   перед ними**:
>
> *Так и жила она без любви, **только** надеясь на нее...*

Comment: А тогда начсет парной закрывающей оборот запятой, если такие обороты ***выделяются***?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все равно осталась тень сомнения. Если убрать оборот, начинающийся с "лишь", предложение перестанет нести свой первоначальный смысл. Тогда можем ли мы считать деепричастие "убедившись" частью сказуемого? И действительно ли нужно разрывать смысловое сказуемое запятой? И как влияет на это "лишь"? Простите за наивные, наверно, вопросы, но я в этом деле профан полный.

Answer (score 2):

Склоняюсь к мысли, что здесь особый случай и запятая не нужна.
В принципе-то - да, деепричастный оборот, начинающийся с "лишь" обособляется по общим правилам.

Но мне кажется, здесь два однородных обстоятельства "убедившись в..." и "с учетом...", соединенные союзом "и". При такой схеме обособление отдельного деепричастного оборота невозможно из-за однородности и союза, а на обособление всего ряда однородных членов нет никаких подходящих правил.

Остается объявить весь оборот (включая "лишь") неким аналогом деепричастия - обстоятельства, тесно связанного по смыслу со сказуемым. В таком случае обособление не требуется. Обычно, правда, таким бывает только одиночное деепричастие (типа "он побежал прихрамывая"), но, тут уж очень хочется признать таковым и весь оборот. Другого варианта предложить не могу.
(+)
Ссылка на правило:

§ 71. Деепричастия и деепричастные обороты не обособляются:

> ....
>
> 3) если деепричастие или деепричастный оборот оказываются в ряду
>   однородных членов предложения, выраженных другими частями речи: Он
>   говорил шепотом и ни на кого не глядя; Клим Самгин шагал по улице
>   бодро и не уступая дорогу встречным людям (М. Г.);

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=198
(Лопатин)

У Розенталя видел тоже в подобной формулировке, но не могу что-то найти.

Comment: Согласен. Хотя идея аналогии с одиночным деепричастием избыточна. Хватит и однородности.

Comment: Спасибо. Хочется ссылку на правило, вашу мысль подтверждающее.

Comment: @PaprikashLi Вот ссылка на правило: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=198  - это пункт 3) Впрочем, сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Comment: @behemothus, самое интересное, что если вбить мое предложение в гугл, ответы буду через строчку - с запятой и без, с запятой и без)

Comment: И да, а что с лишь?

Comment: @PaprikashLi, что через строчку - не сомневаюсь. С первого прочтения может показаться, ччто правила вступают в противоречие, поэтому и нужна системность и самокритичность, а не святая вера в первре найденное правило, смысл которого даже не всегда правильно понят (тут и у нас есть такие любители кидаться формулировками раньше чем думать).

Comment: Я полагаю, что формулировка об однородности членов имеет больший приоритет, чем требование обособлять любой деепричастный оборот, поскольку в ней явно говорится об условиях, **отменяющих** необходимость обособления, а во всех правилах, требующих обособление, включая и злополучное "лишь", ничего об отмене правила однородности не содержится. .

Comment: Правило в отношении оборотов с "лишь" на самом деле не является системообразующим, оно лишь о частном случае, который и по общим правилам решается аналогичным способом, можно специально не оговаривать, это слово ничего нового не добавляет. Просто запомнить, видимо проще.

Comment: behemothus, обратите внимание на то, что в приведённых в ПАС примерах неособления деепричастных оборотов _(Он говорил шепотом **и** ни на кого не глядя; Клим Самгин шагал по улице бодро **и** не уступая дорогу встречным людям)_  эти обороты **присоединены** к впереди стоящим  однородным членам **с помощью союза "и"**. Запятая **перед** "и" в них была бы просто неуместна. У нас несколько иной случай: дееприч. оборот **открывает** ряд однородных.  Корявое какое-то у нас предложение...

Comment: @slava1947, да обратил. Там первым идет однородный член в виде другой части речи. Но не вижу, откуда такая идея, что в случае иного порядка что-то меняется. Неубиенный аргумент: где вторая запятая? Деепричестный оборот ***выделяется*** запятыми, а не ***отделяется*** одной.

Answer (score 1):

1) Согласно интонации, **пауза здесь не делается** и тогда запятая не нужна, ударение переносится на однородные члены: Продолжать переход можно лишь убедившись в безопасности дальнейшего движения и с учетом сигнала светофора.

В этом случае деепричастие **имеет значение наречия, является обстоятельством образа действия и не обособляется.**

2) Можно предположить, что нет запятой и в предложении без однородных членов (**нет паузы - нет запятой**): Продолжать переход можно лишь убедившись в безопасности дальнейшего движения.

3) Вот примеры необособленных  оборотов при отсутствии паузы:  Можно прожить и не хвастая умом, без этих  разговоров. Она прошла улыбаясь и с таким видом, как будто шла приказать что-то.

Comment: При чем здесь паузы?! Вы напираете на паузы, между тем ваши примеры совершенно типичны и рассматриваются во всех учебниках и справочниках без всякого привлечения "пауз". Точнее даже так: "паузы" – следствие синтаксиса, а не наоборот. И пунктуация – следствие синтаксиса. Поэтому выводить пунктуацию из "пауз" по меньшей мере странно.

Comment: Запятая в этом случае не нужна, т. к. деепричастие оказывается в  ряду однородных членов предложения, выраженных другими частями речи. ( Академический справочник).

Comment: Вы напираете на паузы, между тем ваши примеры совершенно типичны и рассматриваются во всех учебниках и справочниках без всякого привлечения "пауз".  === Не заметил такого. Sibylia отнюдь не "напирает", это Вы совершенно неверно трактуете, а интонационный принцип пунктуации никто не отменял.

Comment: "В этом случае деепричастие имеет значение наречия, является обстоятельством образа действия и не обособляется." === хотя в целом мысль правильна, но в данном случае не проходит. Уберите конец, все, начиная со слов "с учетом ..." - и запятая необходимо выскочит.  Тут все-таки однородность существеннее.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Немного не поняла с паузами. При чем здесь они? Мы же не на основе пауз запятые ставим (не всегда, по крайне мере), тем более в моем случае.

Comment: Вообще говоря, интонация складывается из пауз и ударений. Давайте попробуем заменить деепричастный оборот придаточным предложением: ПродолжАть переход можно, если только вы убедились в безопАсности дальнейшего движения и с учетом сигнала светофОра. Ударение падает на первое слово, и мы имеем четко выраженную паузу между главной и придаточной частью. Вернемся к нашему предложению и поставим ударение также на первом слове: ПродолжАть переход можно, лишь убедившись в безопасности дальнейшего движения и с учетом сигнала светофора. И кажется, в этом случае запятую НУЖНО ПОСТАВИТЬ.

Comment: А теперь перенесем ударение на деепричастие: Продолжать переход можно лишь убедИвшись в безопасности дальнейшего движения и с учЁтом сигнала светофора. Теперь пауза не обозначена, запятая не ставится. Получается, что задача имеет ДВА РЕШЕНИЯ, и именно интонация (паузы и ударения) помогает нам получить ответ.