# Нужна ли запятая? 6

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая перед деепричастным оборотом?

Создать максимальный ΔPmax можно (,) создавая вакуум после ИА.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь скорее не нужно. В научном стиле такие обороты воспринимаются как одиночное обстоятельство, к тому же без деепричастия с зависимым словом в корне изменится смысл.

Вот сравните.
[Запятая перед "лишь" + деепричастие](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423565)

(+)
Вот более "офциальная" формулировка

[обособления не требуется]
1) если оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания:

http://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/

Answer (score 1):

**Создать максимальный ΔPmax** /пауза/ **можно создавая вакуум после ИА**.

Оборот не обособляется, так как является смысловым центром высказывания

Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке

Розенталь Д.Э. §94. Обособленные обстоятельства Примечание. **Деепричастные обороты не обособляются:**
а) если оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) **тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания**, например: Она сидела чуть откинув голову, задумчивая и грустная (Г. Марков) (указывается не просто, что «она сидела», а «сидела с откинутой головой»); Мальчик шел прихрамывая на левую ногу, Это Упражнение делают стоя на вытянутых носках;Они жили ни с кем не знакомясь. Надев тесный башмачок, сестрица ходила прихрамывая на левую ногу. Золушка работала напевая веселые песенки.

Примечание: повтор "создать и создавая".